# Chopping string everytime a ; is there R

Tags: r, character

I have a string in which the entries are delimited by a `;`.

```
abc;def;tyu;poi;asf;ghl
```

Is there a function in R which allows me to split up this string into

```
abc
def
tyu
```

all being seperate objects so that I can seperately access and index them?

Is there a way to do this without a character argument? Ny directly indexing a cell in a data frame? The cell looks like the string shown above but if I try

```
strsplit(k[1,8],split=';')
```

there is an error non character argument.

Comment: What does `k` look like? What is `k[1:8]`. You have 6 entries in the data you posted above. Is this a small fragment of a much larger input dataset?

Comment: k[1,1:8] is a cell in a dataframe with the input abc;defg;hijk;lmn;o

Comment: What do you mean "without a character argument"? `strsplit` works only on character vectors. Maybe your `k[1,8]` is a `factor` (in which case `strsplit` -as documented- gives an error)?

Comment: Hold on, `k[1,1:8]` should be the first row and columns one to 8. It *can't* be a single *cell*. Do you mean `k[1,8]`? The first row 8th column? When you read in the data use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.table` or `read.delim` or `read.csv` to ensure you have character data and not factors as @alexis_laz and AnandaMahto points out.

Answer (score 4):

```
items <- scan(text="abc;def;tyu;poi;asf;ghl", sep=";", what="")
Read 6 items
 as.matrix(items)
#----------
     [,1] 
[1,] "abc"
[2,] "def"
[3,] "tyu"
[4,] "poi"
[5,] "asf"
[6,] "ghl"
```

If these are items in a data.frame, it's likely that you *should* have used read.delim with sep=";" and probably stringsAsFactors=FALSE. You can still extract from a factor value with `as.character`:

```
df <- data.frame(a="abc;def;tyu;poi;asf;ghl")
items <- scan(text=df[1,1], sep=";", what="")
Error in textConnection(text) : invalid 'text' argument
# Use as.character instead
items <- scan(text=as.character(df[1,1]), sep=";", what="")
Read 6 items
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without having to enter a character argument but directly to index a cell in a data frame like scan(k[,8],sep=';',what='')

Comment: @TimHeinert you'd probably get more willing help if you'd *ever* accepted *any* answer to your previous 17 questions. Please see the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page to understand how the Q&A works. I'm pretty sure at least some answers should have been accepted by pressing the little green check mark next to the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use the `strsplit` function.

```
> strsplit('abc;def;ghi', split = ';')
[[1]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"
```

Note that `strsplit` is vectorized, and it returns a list of results, also if you just feed one string. To get only that one string:

```
strsplit('abc;def;ghi', split = ';')[[1]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"
```

the advantage of the vectorization is that you can feed `strsplit` a vector of strings:

```
> strsplit(rep('abc;def;ghi', 10), split = ';')
[[1]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"

[[2]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"

[[3]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"

[[4]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"

[[5]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"

[[6]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"

[[7]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"

[[8]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"

[[9]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"

[[10]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"
```

Comment: however, do I need a character argument for stringsplit? I wanted to do this directly with the cell of a data frame. However, when I try 
strsplit(k[,8], split=';') i get an error non-character argument

Comment: using `fixed=TRUE` will make things considerably faster depending on the size of vector.

Comment: okay..but for me the main problem is that I am directly indexing an element in a data frame so I don't have a string yet

Comment: @TimHeinert, I suggest you edit your question to make this clear.